# Users photos from MS Graph

Tags: outlook, adaptive-cards

In my Adaptive card, I want to show the users photo. like so:

[image]

So when I put in the photo, it doesn't display in Outlook

So my card looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "Image",
    "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me@email.com/photo/$value",
    "size": "small",
    "style": "person"
}
```

It doesn't appear in outlook:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get the user photo from MS Graph showing on the Adaptive Card?

Answer (score 0):

Typical, as soon as you pose a question, you find a solution.

If your URL for the photo is:
https://outlook.office365.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email=me@email.com&UA=0&size=HR96x96

Then the photo shows up when testing in Outlook 365 on the web

Unfortunately it just shows nothing in Outlook on Windows

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your two examples, you are retrieving the image from:

1. An authenticated endpoint (Graph API), which just won’t work (images need to be accessible anonymously)
2. By calling into an undocumented OWA API, which works in OWA because your card is running in the same context but won’t work in Outlook (or anywhere else) because, well, it’s not OWA

Please do not retrieve images from authenticated or undocumented APIs. I unfortunately do not have a good solution for retrieving the user's picture to show in your card at this time.